# Disabling GridView Scroll and enabling Scroll view in Android

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

I want to seat a seat layout in my Android Activity I want my seat layout to be wholy visible which is inside a Grid View and instead of grid View to scroll I want my Scroll View should scroll, after disabling the grid view scroll also the scroll view is not working can anyone help me with this ?

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                >


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/wheel"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/mywheel" />

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/grid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/wheel"
                    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
                    android:numColumns="5" />
```

And the below code is for disabling the Scrolling in my grid View

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

sadly thats not possible using "classic" `View`s like `ScrollView` and `GridView` - some days ago Android wasn't prepared for nested scrolling at all... you can try to migrate `GridView` to some custom `NestedGridView` theoretically, but I would advise to convert `GridView` to `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` - current version of `RecyclerView` supports `wrap_content` for height and is much more flexible, you will disallow scroll easily for this `View` keeping whole `ScrollView` container scrollable

below snippet doesn't work because you are returning `true` when `ACTION_MOVE` occurs. this `true` value means "yes, Ive already handled this move, dont dispatch it further" - `GridView` does nothing then, but returns `true`, so `ACTION_MOVE` will never be dispatched and obtained/handled by `ScrollView`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
}
```

edit: there is also possiblity for dispatching touch (methods `onInterceptTouchEvent`, `dispatchTouchEvent` and similar) - that will be hard and tricky to share touch in your case (one scroll inside second scroll), but maybe worth trying if you have very complicated adapter for `GridView`

edit for comment:

replace your `GridView` XML declaration with this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/wheel"
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="90dp" />
```

`android:numColumns="5"` line removed, this will be declared by `GridLayoutManager` in code

```
int numColumns = 5;
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numColumns));
```

you need to edit your adapter, now it should `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.GridViewHolder>`. more about this adapter in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: can you help me with recycler view ?